# How To Stop BringToFront() Moving User Control To Top Left of Window?

Tags: c#, winforms, bringtofront

I'm currently working on a small project, using user controls to bring up different windows part of my windows. When a sidebar is clicked, one of the user controls is brought to the front by BringToFront(). This uses an instance of the User Control via code, to which the function is called.

```
SelectionPanel.Height = btnSideHome.Height;
this.Controls.Add(HomePage.Instance);
HomePage.Instance.BringToFront();
```

However, upon build, when `HomePage.Instance.BringToFront()` is called after the window is initialised, in the `public Form1()` class, the HomePage user control instantiates at the top left of the window, rather than at `200,61`, where it is placed in the form designer.

What is the issue here, and how can I remedy it?

Comment: Not enough code to help.  Show the minimal code that duplicates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply ensure that the control renders in the correct location **before** calling **BringToFront**
with the following.

```
    HomePage.Instance.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out how it's done.

I created a new Point entity with the co-ordinates via the statement

```
Point refpoint = new Point(200,61);
```

Then by calling this reference point when I wanted to set the location of something to this point via

```
HomePage.Instance.Location = refpoint;
```

And this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a Startlocation that is you can set to manual before the form is opened